# Solving these set of equations with complex parameters

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value

For $\{a,b,c\}\in \mathbb{C}$ and $\{\gamma,N\}\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, I have an equation

```
eq[c_, Ν_, γ_] := ((b - (I c)/2 + a γ) ((-1 +
      b - (I c)/2 + a γ)/(-1 + b + (I c)/2 + 
     a γ))^(-1 + Ν))/(b + (I c)/2 + a γ) + (
  Gamma[1 - (I c)/a - γ] Gamma[
    1 + (I c)/a - γ + Ν/2])/(
  Gamma[1 + (I c)/a - γ] Gamma[
    1 - (I c)/a - γ + Ν/2])
```

Now, I want to find $\{a,b\}\in\mathbb{C}$ numerically, because doesn't look like it can solve analytically. So I wanted to try something like

```
NSolve[{eq[0.3+0.1I,6,1]==0,eq[0.3+0.1I,6,2]==0},{a,b}]
```

But this ran forever and gave me no result. Is there a way to make it solve for this?

Comment: [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) is a protected symbol, you cannot use it as a variable. This is the reason why it's being written with a different color than your other variables.

Comment: ```Limit[{eq[0.3 + 0.1 I, 6, 1, a, b],  eq[0.3 + 0.1 I, 6, 2, a, b]}, a -> -∞]``` gives {0., 0.}, so the solution is `a = -∞` . Do you have any other constraints?

Comment: Instead of doing an `NSolve` you could do a minimize a sum of squares of the norms of each complex value: ```NMinimize[{Abs[eq[0.3 + 0.1 I, 6, 1, a, b]]^2 + 
   Abs[eq[0.3 + 0.1 I, 6, 2, a, b]]^2, Abs[a] < 100000, 
  Abs[b] < 100000}, {a, b}]``` - I've adjusted `eq` to take `a,b` as arguments too.

Comment: @Roman, the ````Ν ````  used here is ````\[CapitalNu]```` not ````N````

Comment: @flinty, yeah the other constraints are that no matter what $\gamma$ I use for a fixed $N$ value, it should give me the same $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: @flinty Do ````NMinimize```` search for complex coefficients also? I think it is only trying to search for $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}$ this way.

Comment: @Roman although it's moot, you actually can use `N` to name a pattern in a `:=` function definition—it will just mean that you won't be able to use the built-in meaning of `N` in the definition.

Comment: @thorimur good luck with debugging the code then :-) or, even better, someone else's code that uses `N` or `\[CapitalNu]` for giggles.

Comment: @Roman Oh definitely! Not recommending it, haha, just wanted to mention the behavior. (Also worth noting that `\[CapitalNu]` is at least distinguishable from `N` in Mathematica's default font, although they're still very easy to confuse—`\[CapitalNu]` has serifs!)

Comment: @user824530 yes you're right it does not search for complexes - but you can split a,b up into `ua+va I` and `ub + vb I` and do a search over ua,va,ub,vb - but it's a similarly boring answer - the imaginary parts of a and b want to be at infinity.